# How can i make global textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I work with a lot of page. I calculate some variable other pages and i want write the result other page. How can i make this?

I tried make static textbox but it did not work.

I can make the static variables but i want to static textbox. I want to access to textbox for every page.

Comment: If you're using WPF then you should be binding to a ViewModel object for each form. Have them share a global string field (make sure that it is IObservable so one form knows when another has changed it)

Comment: Re-reading the question, this is multiple tabs on one form? If yes, then just bind multiple text boxes (one per tab) to the same field.

Comment: I have multiple page.

Comment: But in the calculate page i dont want any textbox or something i have only datagrid in this page.

Comment: Put text boxes on those pages where you want them. Bind them to the same field.

Comment: I can not access textbox in calculate section. Because my textbox is in different page. Also i can not create text box in calculate section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a utility like MVVM light that implements a messenger service. Every page that needs to change to the textbox can send a message with the new contents and the page with the textbox can subscribe to those messages.

It seems like you're coupling data and pages much too tightly. In general your views and your data should be completely separated. If you do your data calculations in totally separate classes it is usually easier to get that data wherever you need it. If you're not using the MVVM pattern you should consider it.